# Choice Router Expression Mule

Tags: mule, mule-component

I am building an api to which i am sending a json request as below :

```
{
  "type":"string",
  "code": 101
}
```

I am using a choice router and i am routing the message based in the code .
i.e if code is not 101 and 100 then when condition will be executed 
When Expression is - `#[json:code != 101 && json:code != 100]`
but even if code is 103 the above experession is returning true.

Comment: code is in double quotes

Comment: Wouldn't you expect it to return true? 103 is not 101, and it's not 100.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your comment "code is in double quotes" means the payload is like this:

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "code": "100"
}
```

If so, I'd recommend you convert it to Java and work from there. If the code is a string you need to acount for that as `100 != '100'`:

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
<choice doc:name="Choice - Code?">
    <when expression="#[payload.code != '101' &amp;&amp; payload.code != '100']">
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger - Do this"/>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger - Do that"/>
    </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Json to Object transformer before using JSON payload

### Use (and , or) instead of (&&,||) for Logical operators in mule: [DataWeaveLogicalOperators](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/dw-operators#logical-operators)

xml config code,

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="json to obj"/>
<choice doc:name="Choice">
    <when expression="#[payload.code != 101 and payload.code != 100]">
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="logger"/>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="default"/>
    </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Comment: OP is not using DataWeave. `&&` and `||` are the appropriate types of logical operators for OP's use case, which uses MEL.